# OpenXML - Remove TableCaption in Word doc

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a number of tables in a Word template that are being manipulated with OpenXML. Some of them may need to be removed depending on conditions, in which case I use this code:

```
table.RemoveAllChildren();
table.Remove();
```

Which does remove the `Table` and all rows, but not the `TableCaption`.

I use `foreach (Table t in XMLReport.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Table>().ToList())` so the ToList() allows me to remove while iterating. And the tables themselves are removed from the document, but the captions remain. I did try adding the captions into a list and removing them outside of the loop, but that didn't work. Setting the text, assigning to a new `TableCaption`, nothing appears to modify them. Deleting the `TableProperties` parent and all of its children doesn't do anything either. Calling `Remove()` on the `TableCaption` does not work as well.

What is the proper way to remove the `TableCaption`?

Full code:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\path\XML in.docx");
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument XMLDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {                    
                foreach (Table t in XMLDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Table>().ToList())
                {
                    //switch case
                        if (object1.prop1.Count == 0)
                        {
                            table.RemoveAllChildren();
                            table.Remove();
                        }
                }                    
            }                
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\path\XML out.docx", stream.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works with a little planning. The table captions that you see in the actual document are Paragraph objects to OpenXML, and these can be removed. So I created a list with the text of each caption, and then during my for loop over the tables I remove the strings that need to stay in the doc. Then I get all paragraph descendants in the document, and filter to the ones that are an exact match to one of the remaining paragraph elements. Then I just remove those paragraph elements.